# How do I pass an object or array from a parent to its partial in Jade?

Tags: pug

I'm using Grunt to pass some JSON data to a Jade template. I want to iterate over this data, and pass any found objects or arrays to a partial. From that partial, I would like to grab properties from the data and apply them to a template.

This seems to work fine in a case like this:

```
Main.jade:

for val in data
    if val.type === "title-section"
        -var destCity = val.copy.destCity
        include ./partials/Title.jade


Title.jade:

p #{destCity}
```

But in my case, I'd like to pass an object so I don't have to write out every variable to pass, like this:

```
Main.jade:

for val in data
    if val.type === "title-section"
        -var obj = val
        include ./partials/Title.jade


Title.jade:

p #{obj.copy.destCity}
```

When I run this, I get the error `Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?